# Is it normal for a query to spawn three query processes?

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, amazon-rds

I have a rails application and am trying to troubleshoot some database performance issues, and I just noticed, when I make a query from the rails console:

```
MyModel.where("field ILIKE '%hello%'")
```

when I look at postgres for active queries:

```
SELECT pid, age(clock_timestamp(), query_start), usename, query FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state != 'idle' AND query NOT ILIKE '%pg_stat_activity%';
```

I am seeing:

```
 28877 | 00:00:00.868747 | me | SELECT "shares".* FROM "shares" WHERE (message ilike '%hello%')
 28960 | 00:00:00.868757 | me | SELECT "shares".* FROM "shares" WHERE (message ilike '%hello%')
 28961 | 00:00:00.868759 | me | SELECT "shares".* FROM "shares" WHERE (message ilike '%hello%')
(3 rows)
```

I was very concerned that one command is spawning 3 processes???  Is this normal?

Comment: Could be a parallel proces, to improve performance. Details are missing to be sure about this, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html

Comment: I believe this is not showing what you think it is. 1) Add the `state` field to your query 2) `clock_timestamp()` will change within a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `backend_type` column of `pg_stat_activity`, and you will probably see that two of these processes are parallel workers. You are seeing parallel query in action.